# Relative atomic mass calculation

Tags: atoms

In my textbook it states that relative atomic mass of an element Y is equal to the average mass off one atom of element Y multiplied by 12 divided by the mass of one atom of carbon 12.

What is the intuition behind his? I can't understand where this formula comes from. Additionally isn't the mass of carbon 12 defined to be 12 units hence the 12s cancel out anyways?

Comment: Carbon-12 is a name, much like Ivan is my name. You can't cancel anything out of it.

Comment: $$\frac {12x}{y}=  \frac {x}{(\frac {y}{12})}$$

Relative atomic masses refer to 1/12 of the mass of 1 atom of carbon-12 ( 126C ), which is conventionally chosen as the reference unit.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the definition of your textbook like this :
The relative atomic mass of an element Y is equal to the average mass of one atom of element Y divided by 1/12 of the mass of one atom of carbon 12. And I think you will accept this new definition.

Comment: By "average mass of atom Y" is this referring to the SI mass?

Answer (score 1):

**Atomic masses are awkwardly small in SI units: for convenience they are measured relative to a standard**

We could measure atomic mass in SI units which would result in multiples of about $1.66 \times 10^{-27} kg$ but this would be pretty inconvenient when doing any calculations or comparing nuclear masses.

When chemists want to talk about relative mass of atoms it is far more convenient to use a different unit that makes the relative numbers small. This is sometimes called the dalton (Da) or atomic mass unit (AMU). But these numbers are not exact multiples of the number of nuclei as the energy involved in nuclear forces is so large that it impacts the resulting mass (nuclear masses are lower than the sum of the masses of the protons and neutrons involved). So chemists have to choose a *specific* nucleus as the reference against which other nuclei can be weighed. That nucleus is, historically, $\ce{^12C}$ which has 12 nucleons. So other nuclei are "weighed" relative to that nucleus (or, strictly 1/12 of it so the results are approximately relative to a single nucleon).

This explains the math.